# Drupal 7 - Import file from a tempory directory on the site into file field on the node

Tags: drupal-7, filefield

Drupal 7 file field question:  Is it possible to ftp files to a temporary location, then move them into a file field on a drupal node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each file, call this function:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_data